# Running native SELECT and UPDATE with JTA in one Transaction

Tags: hibernate, transactions

i would like to know if it is possible to run a SELECT and an UPDATE statement in Hibernate within just one transaction.
There is a very special situation which i cannot change. So i have to call a SQL function and then UPDATE a Table.
This function creates some temporary stuff which is used to update the Table. 
If it is not called within the same transaction a trigger causes the update to fail.

So, please do not tell me i should change that :D i would if i could.
But anyhow ... here is my code which should run in one transaction, but which does not do so:

```
 @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
 public int nativeUpdateWithParams(String currentUser, boolean setCurrentUser, String nativeSql, Object...obj) {        
    try {
        Query query;
        if (nativeSql != null) {
            if (setCurrentUser) {
                String sql = "SELECT module.current_user(:param1)";
                query = em.createNativeQuery(sql);
                query.setParameter("param1", currentUser);
                query.getSingleResult();
            } 
            query = em.createNativeQuery(nativeSql);
            int i=0;
            for (Object param:obj) {
                i++;
                query.setParameter("param"+i, param);
            }
            int result = query.executeUpdate();
            return result;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {                      
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {            
        return 0;            
    }
}
```

Hibernate seems to create at least two transactions to execute the SELECT and UPDATE.
If i change the Transactionattribute to:

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.MANDATORY)
```

create a transaction on the client (which i always commit .. no matter what happends) 
and i write:

```
String test = "SELECT module.current_user('userXYZ')";
query = em.createNativeQuery(test + ";" + nativeSql);
```

i do get an execption similar like "update returns something...." but it works.
It would be really nice if someone could help me solving this issue!

Thank you

Edit:
The exception will not help a bit, because it is the result of the trigger from the "to update" table.

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FEHLER: You are not a real person.
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1525)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1309)
at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:188)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:452)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:354)
at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:308)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:210)
... 72 more
```

To get in detail:
if i do the following on a console/Postgres it works like a charm:

```sql
begin transaction;
SELECT module.current_user('userXYZ');
update public.carrier set carrier_comment='whatever' where carrier_id=57300;
commit;
```

i works!

if i do it like that:

```sql
SELECT module.current_user('userXYZ');
update public.carrier set carrier_comment='whatever' where carrier_id=57300;
```

i do get the error as descriped above: "you are not a real person"

**Edit2:**
If anybody ever has the same problem, the solution is just as simply as stupid :)
Just check your glassfish settings (JDBC - JDBC Connection Pools) and make sure that you do not have activated:

Transaction: Non Transactional Connections: Enabled

Thats it. After changing this settings, the transaction are working as expected. So this was not a Hibernate issue...

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Why couldn't you? What do you think Hibernate does when you tell it to get a object from the DB, and then update this object? It executes a SQL select query to get the object, and then a SQL update query to update it.

Comment: But i am not talking about a hibernate Object. This scenario described above does not work. If i do a 

begin transaction;
SELECT module.current_user('user');
UPDATE ....;
commit;

then it works. I thought that TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW means, that this function is executed in one transaction. But it seems not to be...

Comment: If you get an exception, please include the full stack trace of the exception. Marking the methd with REQUIRES_NEW ensures that a new transaction is used to execute everyting in the method. This is fine. Don't assume that it's a problem with transactions, and show us the full exception stack trace (and the actual code that is used).

Comment: If I understand what you're doing correctly, you're trying to change the current user before executing an update. I don't know if it's possible or if it's a good idea with a pooled connection, but I'm no PostgreSQL expert. I searched the doc of PostgreSQL, and didn't find any indication about this syntax of current_user. It seems to be defined as a read_only function, without argument. What I found was "set role": http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-info.html

Comment: you are right, the problem is the login structure (which i cannot change). My app runs as "myapp" user and the users login via LDAP. Thats all fine so far, but there is one special case, where my we want to log the changes. That for we need the LDAP user and not the application. I think that is why this construct exists. Via the select there will be created a dummy table which will be dropped on commit. So i think hibernate commits my select before updating my table.
Fact is, that i cannot change it. I just want to execute a SELECT and UPDATE within ONE transaction via Hibernate :).